# Magento Command for bulk Optimizing existing Product images

Tags: magento2.3, product-images, magento-community, optimization

How to optimize **existing** Product images via commandline, similar to resize command.

```
php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-image-resizing.html
This is Magento documentation regarding Javascript optimization & Resize options for Product images at Upload time.

My query is how to optimize **existing** Product images, if I change Javascript optimization in Adminpanel to 90%, so it will only affect, further uploaded images via AdminPanel.

What about existing Images, how to batch process existing images?

Although, there is a resize command in Magento, is there a bulk optimize **Magento command**?

Answer (score 0):

Another very important point on SEO is the optimization and compression of images on the site. Here is an interesting article on this topic: https://optipic.io/en/blog/images-seo-optimization/